# logstash: What should be the file location in email attachments filed?

Tags: logstash

Can anyone please explain how the java log exceptions should be sent as attachments via email in logstash? What will be the file location to be given in the attachments filed? Please find the config file where there is a filter to get the exceptions.
    input {
        file {
        type => "syslog"
        path => ""
        add_field => ["File", "a.log"]
        }

```
}


filter {
        if ("INFO" in [message]){
                    mutate {
                         add_field => [ "level", "INFO" ]
                       }
                  }

       else if ("error" in [message]){
                   mutate {
                             add_field => [ "level", "ERROR" ]
                          }
               }

       else if ("Debug" in [message]){
                   mutate {
                            add_field => [ "level", "DEBUG" ]
                         }
                }

       multiline{
                  pattern => "^\s"
                  what => "previous"
                  add_tag => ["exception"]
                }

        if ("multiline" in [tags]) {
                mutate {
                            add_field => [ "level", "exception" ]
                    }
                 }
             }
output {
  if [message] =~ /exception/ {
            email {
                    type => "syslog"
                    body => "Triggered in: %{@message}"
                    attachments => 
                    from => "abc@xyz.com"
                    subject => "This is a LogStash alert"
                    to => "lmn@por.co.in"
                    }
        }


 }
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible, at least not without using a ruby filter to flush the exception data to a temporary file and passing that to the email output. Doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: Can we have a filter as above for elastic search output and save that data in a file and give this file location for email output?

Comment: Theoretically possible I'm sure, but _much_ more difficult than just modifying the email output to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but it seems like you could use the 'file' output to create the file, and then feed this to the 'attachment' parameter of the 'email' output.

I don't see a way to cleanup the files that have been created, but a simple cron job could do that (or you could modify the email output to remove the attachments).

EDIT:

When you use the file{} output, you specify the filename to be used:

```
output {
  file {
    path => "foo.txt"
  }
}
```

You would then specify this file name as the attachment in the email output:

```
output {
  email {
    attachments => [ "foo.txt" ]
  }
}
```

You can use variables in the filenames, too: "foo-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.txt", etc.

Note that the email stanza is pseudo-code as there's no example of the attachments syntax in the doc.

Comment: I am able to get the output to a file and attach this file to email. But do u know how to find out the latest file on  the disk and attach that?

Comment: Hi Alain I can create the date wise files but the thing is the attachment field does not take regular expressions and thus i cannot specify a regex to pick the latest file for attachment, it  should be the complete name of the file. Do you have any input on how we  can get the last date file as attachment?

Comment: Yeah, it can be hit-or-miss where they enable variables.  You're very close - how about making the required changes to outputs/email.rb ?

Comment: I went through the file email.rb. But unfortunately I couldn't get how to make changes to get the attachments. Do you have any views on this?